# HiddenField1 value is empty

Tags: c#, .net

I try to add form jquery on my page. I have this code piece:

```
<form id="form" class="blocks" action="form.aspx" method="post">
    <p>
        <label>Name:</label>
        <input type="text" class="text" id="name1"  name="name"  />
    </p>
<input runat="server" type="submit" class="btn" onclick="return xy();"  value="Submit"/>
            </p>
</form>

<form id="form1" runat="server" action="form.aspx" method="post">
    <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" />
</form>
```

And this:

```
function xy()
{
    $("#HiddenField1").val($("#name1").val());
    alert($("#HiddenField1").val());
}
```

This alert works correctly, and I want to use `HiddenField1.Value` as a `string` in C#. My code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string string1 = HiddenField1.Value;
}
```

`string1` is `null`. Why it is `null`?

Comment: How is HiddenField1 assigned a value?

Answer (score 1):

It depends. You must first call function xy() for the HiddelField1.value to have a value. 
I cant see that you call it.

Like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //call xy() here
    string string1 = HiddenField1.Value;
}
```

Comment: oops there was a missing part!
<input runat="server" type="submit" class="btn" onclick="return xy();"  value="Submit"/>
   </p>

Answer (score 0):

You just need to move you Hidden variable to be in the same Form with the Submit button and remove the second Form tag. 
So your HTML should be changed to be like the following:

```
<form id="form" class="blocks" action="WebForm1.aspx" method="post" runat="server">
<asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" />
<p>
    <label>
        Name:</label>
    <input type="text" class="text" id="name1" name="name" />
</p>
<input id="Submit1" runat="server" type="submit" class="btn" onclick="return xy();"
    value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the jquery text() function

```
function xy() {
  $("#HiddenField1").val($("#name1").text());
}
```

Comment: I thnk he/she would like to assign a value to the hiddenfield in the client side. I suppose that xy() function is a Javascript function and he/she ask the vlue after a postback.

Comment: i can not use asp button. if i use my form doesn't work correctly.
there was a missing part that:
<input runat="server" type="submit" class="btn" onclick="return xy();"  value="Submit"/>
   </p>